# Setting value on html 5 numeric input doesn't change validity

Tags: javascript, html

If I type into a html 5 numeric input text box some invalid value, say 'abc' then programatically set the value to a valid value it leaves the invalid pseudo class active. Is there any way I can make it validate correctly?

```
<style>
    input[type='number']:invalid { border: 1px solid red !important;}
    input[type='number']:valid { border: 1px solid green !important;  }
</style>
<form>
    Type something invalid:
    <input type='number' id='numericinput' />

    <button onclick="numericinput.value = 5;" type="button">Set to valid</button>
</form>
```

JSfiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/V49B3/1/

Comment: I note I am using Chrome, maybe it works in other browsers!

Comment: I am using Chrome too

Comment: This is a hack rather than a solution, but i noticed clicking the button twice does set the validity. so doing it twice in the onclick also seems to work. onclick="numericinput.value = 5;numericinput.value = 5;" do you need to call to validtate it explicitly, or set focus or something

Comment: @LeonardFeehan: Thanks for this, I agree, it's a bit of a hack but it's all I've got at the moment. I have tried using checkValidity, it didn't work, I'd rather not set focus as this is an update that should be happening in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use an input with the text type and validate the value with the pattern attribute.
You can find some useful regex on [html5pattern](http://html5pattern.com) website.

```
<input type='text' id='numericinput' pattern='[0-9]*'/>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that on the JSfiddle, didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Have you change the CSS: `input[type='text']:invalid`.
I'm using Chrome too and it works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your answer correctly, I want to stay with the number type input box as it provides the correct keyboard layout on mobile devices (I know there is a hack to change the keyboard but would prefer not to go this route :) )

Comment: I didn't think about the keyboard, I completely missed this point :)